# Two algorithms for the Jacobi method: why the time change?

Tags: algorithm, matlab

I have implemented the Jacobi algorithm for iterative solving of linear systems in two ways. They both start with a few checks as to whether or not one can apply the method, then one explicitly constructs the iteration matrix P and the iterations' added vector c, whereas the other calculates the new vector component by component using a subfunction for each iteration. Here's the first one:

```
function [x,nit,t,invt] = jacobi(A,b,tol,x0,NMAX)
%Perfetto equivalente di jacobsparse.m che lavora con A in formato full e
%restituisce sia il tempo impiegato a risolvere il sistema sia quello
%impiegato per invertire la matrice D che serve a calcolare la matrice di
%iterazione.
if nargin < 5
    NMAX=100;
    %Se il max di iterazioni non ? dato, viene automaticamente impostato a
    %100.
    if nargin < 4
        x0=zeros(1,length(A));
        %Se l'innesco non ? dato, viene automaticamente impostato al
        %vettore nullo.
        if nargin < 3
            error('Mi devi dare almeno la matrice, il termine noto e la tolleranza')
            %Se manca anche la tolleranza, non volendo dare un valore di
            %default che non sapevo come sceglierlo, gli faccio dare
            %errore.
        end
    end
end
matsize=size(A);
if matsize(1)~=length(b)
    error('Le dimensioni di matrice e termine noto non concordano')
    %Se b non ? A per un vettore, allora non posso risolvere il sistema.
end
if matsize(2)~=length(x0)
    error('Le dimensioni di matrice e vettore d''innesco non concordano')
    %Se A*x0 non ? definito, l'innesco non ha la dimensione giusta per
    %poter risolvere il sistema.
end
if matsize(1)~=matsize(2)
    error('Non posso applicare il metodo a matrici rettangolari.')
    %Il metodo di Jacobi non si pu? applicare a matrici rettangolari perch?
    %le componenti delle iterate si ricavano in corrispondenza con quelle
    %del termine noto, e se i numeri di componenti di b e di x sono diversi
    %non riesco a risolvere il problema.
end
for i=1:min(size(A))
    if A(i,i)==0
        error('Non posso applicare il metodo causa elemento diagonale (%.0f,%.0f) nullo.',i,i)
        %Il metodo richiede di dividere almeno una volta per ogni elemento
        %diagonale, quindi se un elemento ? nullo ci fermiamo subito, prima
        %che capiti "Division by zero", che poi su MATLAB manco d? errore,
        %d? Inf.
    end
end
nit=0;
incr=tol;
xold=x0;
%Inizializzo queste variabili in modo da poterle usare subito. nit ?
%ovviamente 0, poi viene incrementato; incr lo metto a tol cos? entra nel
%ciclo; xold parte da x0.
diagon=diag(A,0);
D=diag(diagon);
LU=A-D;
tic
Dinv=inv(D);
invt=toc;
P=Dinv*LU;
c=Dinv*b;
tic
while nit < NMAX && incr >= tol
    nit = nit + 1;
    %Incremento il numero di iterazioni.
    xnew = P*xold+c;
    %Ricavo con la subfunction il vettore xnew dell'iterata corrente.
    x = xnew;
    %Metto xnew in x, cos? se si esce x ? gi? sistemato.
    incr = norm(xnew-xold);
    %Salvo la norma dell'incremento.
    xold=xnew;
    %Metto xnew in xold, cosicch? la prossima iterata usi xnew come xold e
    %ricavi il corrispondente xnew.
end
t=toc;
end
```

And here's the second:

```
function [x,nit,t] = jacobsparse(A,b,tol,x0,NMAX)
%Restituisce la soluzione x del sistema con matrice A e b in ingresso,
%ottenuta col metodo di Jacobi con tolleranza tol in ingresso, innesco x0
%in ingresso o automaticamente nullo, e massimo di iterazioni NMAX in
%ingresso o automaticamente 100. Se non ha abbastanza input, d? errore.
%Lavora con A in formato sparse. L'equivalente in formato full ? jacobi.m.
%Restituisce anche il numero di iterazioni effettivamente compiute nit e il
%tempo impiegato t. Si serve di jac_iter.m per le singole iterazioni del
%metodo.
if nargin < 5
    NMAX=100;
    %Se il max di iterazioni non ? dato, viene automaticamente impostato a
    %100.
    if nargin < 4
        x0=zeros(length(A),1);
        %Se l'innesco non ? dato, viene automaticamente impostato al
        %vettore nullo.
        if nargin < 3
            error('Mi devi dare almeno la matrice, il termine noto e la tolleranza')
            %Se manca anche la tolleranza, non volendo dare un valore di
            %default che non sapevo come sceglierlo, gli faccio dare
            %errore.
        end
    end
end
matsize=size(A);
if matsize(1)~=length(b)
    error('Le dimensioni di matrice e termine noto non concordano')
    %Se b non ? A per un vettore, allora non posso risolvere il sistema.
end
if matsize(2)~=length(x0)
    error('Le dimensioni di matrice e vettore d''innesco non concordano')
    %Se A*x0 non ? definito, l'innesco non ha la dimensione giusta per
    %poter risolvere il sistema.
end
if matsize(1)~=matsize(2)
    error('Non posso applicare il metodo a matrici rettangolari.')
    %Il metodo di Jacobi non si pu? applicare a matrici rettangolari perch?
    %le componenti delle iterate si ricavano in corrispondenza con quelle
    %del termine noto, e se i numeri di componenti di b e di x sono diversi
    %non riesco a risolvere il problema.
end
for i=1:min(size(A))
    if A(i,i)==0
        error('Non posso applicare il metodo causa elemento diagonale (%.0f,%.0f) nullo.',i,i)
        %Il metodo richiede di dividere almeno una volta per ogni elemento
        %diagonale, quindi se un elemento ? nullo ci fermiamo subito, prima
        %che capiti "Division by zero", che poi su MATLAB manco d? errore,
        %d? Inf.
    end
end
nit=0;
incr=tol;
xold=x0;
%Inizializzo queste variabili in modo da poterle usare subito. nit ?
%ovviamente 0, poi viene incrementato; incr lo metto a tol cos? entra nel
%ciclo; xold parte da x0.
tic
while nit < NMAX && incr >= tol
    nit = nit + 1;
    %Incremento il numero di iterazioni.
    xnew = jac_iter(A,xold,b);
    %Ricavo con la subfunction il vettore xnew dell'iterata corrente.
    x = xnew;
    %Metto xnew in x, cos? se si esce x ? gi? sistemato.
    incr = norm(xnew-xold);
    %Salvo la norma dell'incremento.
    xold=xnew;
    %Metto xnew in xold, cosicch? la prossima iterata usi xnew come xold e
    %ricavi il corrispondente xnew.
end
t=toc;
end
```

With the following subfunction:

```
function xnew = jac_iter(A,xold,b)
xnew=zeros(length(xold),1);
for i=1:length(xold)
    xnew(i)=b(i);
    %Comincio a mettere b(i) in xnew(i).
    for j=1:i-1
        xnew(i) = xnew(i)-A(i,j)*xold(j);
        %Poi ci sottraggo la somma per j<i di A(i,j)*xold(j).
    end
    for j=i+1:length(xold)
        xnew(i) = xnew(i)-A(i,j)*xold(j);
        %Poi ci sottraggo la somma per j>i.
    end
    xnew(i)=xnew(i)/A(i,i);
    %Infine divido il tutto per A(i,i), cos? divido solo una volta. Il
    %ciclo naturalmente va da 1 a size(xold)=size(xnew).
end
end
```

Sorry for the comments in Italian, but I wrote them in Italian because this is to be put in a "report" in Italian and comments in English would seem out of place. I guess Google shouldn't do too bad on those. If you wish me to translate them, do tell me. Anyway my question is: why is it that the first one, on a 2000-by-2000 sparse matrix in full format, takes about 5.4e-1 seconds to invert the diagonal matrix and 1.8e-1 seconds to solve the system with only 91 iterations out of the maximum of 200 whereas the second one after 200 iterations ends its job having taken 1e4 seconds? THis means that, assuming the time for one iteration is constant, number 2 would take about 5e3 seconds to do the same thing number 1 does in ~2s! Yet they should do more or less the same operations, in a different order! And why is it number 1 converges while number 2 doesn't? Am I missing something here? Finally, I have been told to implement two different functions to apply this algorithm to matrix in full and sparse format, and just can't find any sensible reason why I should. Any ideas on that? PS if you feel I should ask this last question separately, do tell me, and I will.

**Update:**
Following Michael's advice, I wrote the following code:

```
clear all
clc
for i=1:200
    [A,A1]=sparsa2(10*i);
    tic
    xnew=jac_iter(A,zeros(10*i,1),ones(10*i,1));
    times(1,i)=toc;
    toc
    tic
    xnew=jac_iter(A1,zeros(10*i,1),ones(10*i,1));
    times(2,i)=toc;
    toc
    tic
    diagmat=diag(diag(A1,0));
    Dinv=inv(diagmat);
    LU=A1-diagmat;
    P=Dinv*LU;
    c=Dinv*ones(10*i,1);
    times(3,i)=toc;
    toc
    tic
    xnew2=P*zeros(10*i,1)+c;
    times(4,i)=toc;
    toc
end
```

This uses the following function:

```
function [A,A1]=sparsa2(n,dens)
%Crea una matrice n-per-n sparsa con densit? dens tramite sprand; la
%densit? si pu? lasciare automaticamente impostata a 20. La function si
%sincera anche che la diagonale non contenga zeri.
if nargin == 0
    error('Almeno la dimensione me la devi dare, se no come ti faccio la matrice sparsa?')
    %Se non viene data la dimensione, errore.
elseif nargin == 1
    dens = 20;
    %Se non viene data la densit?, si imposta automaticamente a 20.
end
A=rand(n);
%Si crea la matrice.
tol=dens/100;
%Si salva la densit? in formato decimale.
for i=1:n
    for j=1:n
        if A(i,i)<tol && i~=j
            A(i,i)=0;
            %Si impone una sparsit? con densit? di non zeri dens azzerando
            %tutto quello che nella matrice sta sotto a dens/100;
            %ovviamente questo si basa sull'euristica che la probabilit? di
            %ottenere con rand un numero qualunque sia sempre la stessa e
            %evita di azzerare entrate diagonali.
        end
    end
end
for i=1:n
    if A(i,i)==0
        A(i,i)=rand;
    end
    %Visto che questa function devo usarla per fornire matrici a Jacobi, mi
    %sincero che sulla diagonale non ci siano zeri, altrimenti Jacobi non
    %si pu? applicare. Per ottimizzare i tempi non sostituisco con rand
    %tutte le entrate diagonali di A, ma solo quelle nulle, che vengono
    %individuate con un condizionale.
end
A1=A;
A=sparse(A);
%Memorizzo in A1 il formato full, che per ora ? quello di A, e poi metto
%in A il formato sparse.
```

Same as above for the comments in Italian. I'm using `rand` and then zeroing some terms because `sprand`, besides not observing the density requirements for the nonzero (the third parameter is the density of the nonzero, not of the zeroes, right?), takes aaaaaages to produce a matrix, and then it still has to unzero the diagonal, otherwise Jacobi algorithm can't be applied. I got fed up midway through running that code and stopped at about `i=185`, getting the following `times'`:

```
    0.0067    0.0033    0.0029    0.0003
    0.0075    0.0001    0.0003    0.0001
    0.0156    0.0001    0.0552    0.0000
    0.0201    0.0001    0.0003    0.0000
    0.0409    0.0001    0.0003    0.0000
    0.0613    0.0002    0.0004    0.0000
    0.0720    0.0003    0.0006    0.0001
    0.1075    0.0003    0.0007    0.0001
    0.1186    0.0003    0.0009    0.0001
    0.1515    0.0004    0.0008    0.0001
    0.1915    0.0004    0.0010    0.0001
    0.2400    0.0005    0.0015    0.0001
    0.2494    0.0006    0.0025    0.0001
    0.2902    0.0007    0.0026    0.0001
    0.3299    0.0008    0.0026    0.0001
    0.3408    0.0008    0.0029    0.0002
    0.3995    0.0012    0.0038    0.0002
    0.4324    0.0012    0.0039    0.0001
    0.4687    0.0014    0.0062    0.0003
    0.5365    0.0015    0.0061    0.0003
    0.5922    0.0017    0.0072    0.0001
    0.6417    0.0019    0.0070    0.0001
    0.6970    0.0020    0.0076    0.0001
    0.7088    0.0022    0.0082    0.0001
    0.8002    0.0027    0.0087    0.0002
    0.8338    0.0025    0.0117    0.0004
    0.9091    0.0026    0.0105    0.0003
    0.9981    0.0033    0.0110    0.0001
    1.0528    0.0034    0.0121    0.0001
    1.1499    0.0038    0.0117    0.0002
    1.1778    0.0038    0.0143    0.0001
    1.2721    0.0042    0.0156    0.0002
    1.3673    0.0046    0.0182    0.0002
    1.4727    0.0045    0.0183    0.0002
    1.5056    0.0049    0.0211    0.0003
    1.6287    0.0052    0.0214    0.0003
    1.6792    0.0057    0.0163    0.0002
    1.7923    0.0061    0.0226    0.0002
    1.8907    0.0062    0.0220    0.0002
    2.0210    0.0067    0.0227    0.0002
    2.0612    0.0071    0.0281    0.0003
    2.1789    0.0076    0.0290    0.0003
    2.3028    0.0076    0.0274    0.0002
    2.3854    0.0079    0.0253    0.0002
    2.5192    0.0088    0.0326    0.0003
    2.6105    0.0089    0.0314    0.0003
    2.7601    0.0093    0.0375    0.0012
    2.9112    0.0094    0.0340    0.0002
    3.0224    0.0106    0.0350    0.0002
    3.1576    0.0108    0.0420    0.0003
    3.2817    0.0107    0.0357    0.0004
    3.4132    0.0112    0.0392    0.0003
    3.5205    0.0118    0.0505    0.0004
    3.6826    0.0122    0.0432    0.0003
    3.8778    0.0134    0.0581    0.0005
    4.0303    0.0135    0.0499    0.0003
    4.1311    0.0147    0.0496    0.0003
    4.2592    0.0148    0.0583    0.0004
    4.4248    0.0149    0.0625    0.0004
    4.6334    0.0154    0.0580    0.0004
    4.7406    0.0164    0.0566    0.0004
    4.9101    0.0166    0.0676    0.0004
    5.0624    0.0171    0.0616    0.0004
    5.2709    0.0188    0.0762    0.0004
    5.4508    0.0180    0.0739    0.0004
    5.6180    0.0189    0.0724    0.0004
    5.8853    0.0192    0.0825    0.0004
    6.0036    0.0199    0.0798    0.0004
    6.1707    0.0219    0.0968    0.0005
    6.3741    0.0206    0.0880    0.0005
    6.5337    0.0215    0.0915    0.0004
    6.8124    0.0211    0.1028    0.0005
    6.9312    0.0222    0.1058    0.0004
    7.1312    0.0227    0.1030    0.0005
    8.2538    0.0266    0.1238    0.0005
    8.5937    0.0243    0.1033    0.0006
    7.7826    0.0248    0.1040    0.0004
    8.1156    0.0272    0.1137    0.0005
    8.3723    0.0261    0.1245    0.0006
    8.5101    0.0262    0.1351    0.0006
    8.6796    0.0272    0.1374    0.0006
    8.9729    0.0279    0.1339    0.0006
    9.2011    0.0285    0.1350    0.0006
    9.6675    0.0288    0.1466    0.0005
    9.8925    0.0304    0.1452    0.0006
   10.0381    0.0328    0.1553    0.0008
   10.4903    0.0315    0.1671    0.0007
   10.5815    0.0308    0.1627    0.0006
   10.8701    0.0327    0.1761    0.0006
   11.1378    0.0331    0.1651    0.0007
   11.2975    0.0342    0.1768    0.0006
   11.4691    0.0352    0.1916    0.0006
   11.7784    0.0370    0.1795    0.0007
   12.1960    0.0357    0.1776    0.0006
   12.4342    0.0374    0.1897    0.0007
   12.6972    0.0415    0.2034    0.0006
   13.0002    0.0380    0.2269    0.0007
   13.2209    0.0394    0.2218    0.0006
   13.5231    0.0410    0.2234    0.0008
   13.7816    0.0403    0.2123    0.0007
   14.1996    0.0415    0.2354    0.0009
   14.6795    0.0426    0.2491    0.0007
   14.8138    0.0436    0.2456    0.0009
   14.9901    0.0425    0.2394    0.0007
   15.5859    0.0455    0.2608    0.0008
   15.9803    0.0457    0.2673    0.0008
   16.0887    0.0475    0.2418    0.0008
   16.3703    0.0487    0.2887    0.0008
   16.9425    0.0492    0.3165    0.0008
   18.7806    0.0584    0.3333    0.0010
   21.7533    0.0506    0.3116    0.0008
   20.3409    0.0545    0.2927    0.0008
   18.5046    0.0538    0.3411    0.0008
   18.6049    0.0529    0.3154    0.0011
   19.3019    0.0533    0.3359    0.0010
   19.6578    0.0544    0.3567    0.0010
   19.9678    0.0555    0.3432    0.0009
   20.2023    0.0569    0.3234    0.0012
   20.8636    0.0581    0.3588    0.0010
   20.8515    0.0568    0.3348    0.0009
   21.5589    0.0593    0.4119    0.0010
   21.6361    0.0614    0.3526    0.0012
   21.9093    0.0618    0.3932    0.0011
   22.3367    0.0622    0.3873    0.0010
   22.5436    0.0633    0.4033    0.0010
   23.1500    0.0642    0.4152    0.0011
   23.8644    0.0657    0.4237    0.0010
   24.4362    0.0986    0.4828    0.0012
   24.5771    0.0704    0.4227    0.0012
   24.6004    0.0675    0.4672    0.0010
   25.1526    0.0709    0.4508    0.0012
   25.4833    0.0720    0.4298    0.0012
   25.8981    0.0719    0.4657    0.0013
   26.3997    0.0720    0.4826    0.0013
   26.7230    0.0740    0.5216    0.0013
   27.2369    0.0739    0.4747    0.0012
   27.6131    0.0763    0.5270    0.0012
   29.5497    0.0804    0.5495    0.0014
   29.7541    0.0804    0.5224    0.0013
   29.4014    0.0794    0.5366    0.0014
   30.3006    0.0811    0.5419    0.0013
   30.7948    0.0825    0.5798    0.0018
   31.0410    0.0842    0.5704    0.0012
   31.4454    0.0921    0.5945    0.0013
   32.7923    0.0839    0.5688    0.0015
   33.2333    0.0862    0.5950    0.0015
   34.1797    0.0872    0.5905    0.0021
   35.1448    0.0925    0.5921    0.0017
   35.4237    0.0951    0.6729    0.0016
   36.1466    0.0934    0.6738    0.0018
   36.6392    0.0945    0.6435    0.0016
   37.1361    0.0981    0.6345    0.0014
   37.5505    0.0964    0.6789    0.0015
   37.9392    0.0975    0.7185    0.0016
   38.6308    0.0996    1.5555    0.0020
   39.1776    0.0997    0.7734    0.0018
   39.7029    0.1030    0.6917    0.0016
   40.2277    0.1021    0.6831    0.0015
   40.5795    0.1064    0.7645    0.0018
   41.5639    0.1138    0.8422    0.0023
   41.3331    0.1155    0.7962    0.0019
   42.5029    0.1116    0.8032    0.0016
   42.6863    0.1089    0.7750    0.0020
   43.2784    0.1730    2.2928    0.0019
   44.0860    0.1119    0.8629    0.0017
   44.9578    0.1144    0.8481    0.0019
   45.4306    0.1186    1.0030    0.0020
   45.9325    0.1208    0.8851    0.0017
   46.9734    0.1220    0.8957    0.0021
   47.8684    0.1191    0.9411    0.0022
   47.7906    0.1251    0.9779    0.0017
   48.5830    0.1206    0.9621    0.0022
   49.0313    0.1229    0.9828    0.0022
   49.6555    0.1255    0.9881    0.0023
   50.4140    0.1258    0.9727    0.0023
   51.0908    0.1365    0.9776    0.0023
   51.9044    0.1459    1.0970    0.0023
   52.7301    0.1314    1.0280    0.0022
   53.6985    0.1329    1.3397    0.0017
   53.6170    0.1329    1.0780    0.0020
   54.6879    0.1364    1.1436    0.0024
   55.1210    0.1402    1.1096    0.0020
   57.6322    0.1428    1.1453    0.0020
   57.0160    0.1417    1.2097    0.0021
```

I have readied a script to run the missing bit, but I think it may not be necessary. Observe how giving a matrix in `sparse` format increases by like 50 times the amount of time necessary for `jac_iter`, which is the first two columns, `sparse` and `full` respectively. The third column is the time for algorithm 1 to calculate *P* with a full matrix and the last column is an iteration of algorithm 1. As you can see, it takes longer with algorithm 1 if we count the construction of *P*, the opposite otherwise, and in any case a `sparse` matrix takes ages more. Apparently, retrieving entries from `sparse` matrices also takes far longer than retrieving the same entries from `full` matrices. After `F=sprand(4,7,20)`, I ran:

```
tic
F(1,2);
tt(1)=toc;
toc
tic
F1(1,2);
tt(2)=toc;
toc
```

twice, and got:

```
   1.0e-03 *

   0.612686000000000   0.001495000000000


   1.0e-04 *

   0.547670000000000   0.020670000000000
```

On the left, the time for retrieving `F(1,2)`, `sparse` format; on the right, same entry, but from `F1=full(F)`. Anyway over 10 times as much from the sparse matrix. Why is that? And how do I optimize the Jacobi algorithm for sparse matrices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not an expert in matlab but I think that your problem is an universal one. In the first algorithm you make less calculations than in the second one. More precisely in the first case some calculations are executed only once and in the second they are repeated for every iteration of the while loop.

If I understand your code correctly, the following fragment from the first algorithm:

```
diagon=diag(A,0);
D=diag(diagon);
LU=A-D;
tic
Dinv=inv(D);
invt=toc;
P=Dinv*LU;
c=Dinv*b;
```

Is an equivalent of what *jac_iter* function does in the second algorithm. The difference is that this fragment is executed only once just before *while* loop when *jac_iter* function is executed many times within this *while* loop and it is a place for optimization.

**UPDATE**

It seems to me that you shouldn't use sparse matrices if your data are not really sparse i.e. when they contain a lot on non-zero values. In your last example you used the following code *F=sprand(4,7,20)*. The last argument of *sprand* function takes values from 0 to 1. By specifying 20 as the third argument you created a sparse matrix that contains no zeroes.

The following code shows how sparse and full matrices behave depending of the number of zeroes in the matrix. I measured a time of multiplication and of reading all cells in the matrix:

```
density = [0.01, 0.02, 0.05, 0.1, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 0.95];
N = 1000
for x=1:length(density)
    A = sprand(N,N,density(x));
    elapsed(x,1) = density(x);

    tic;
    Z = A*A;
    elapsed(x,2)=toc;

    tic;
    sum = 0;
    for i=1:N
        for j=1:N
            sum = sum + A(i,j);
        end
    end
    elapsed(x,3)=toc;

    B = full(A);

    tic;
    Y = B*B;
    elapsed(x,4)=toc;

    tic;
    sum2 = 0;
    for i=1:N
        for j=1:N
            sum2 = sum2 +  B(i,j);
        end
    end
    elapsed(x,5)=toc;
end
```

The results for N = 100 are:

```
Density   Sparse    Sparse    Full      Full
          multip.   retrieval multip.   retrieval 
0.0100    0.0001    0.0795    0.0030    0.0002
0.0200    0.0001    0.0996    0.0153    0.0002
0.0500    0.0002    0.0959    0.0031    0.0002
0.1000    0.0006    0.1651    0.0007    0.0002
0.2500    0.0013    0.1110    0.0080    0.0002
0.5000    0.0019    0.0898    0.0006    0.0002
0.7500    0.0012    0.0861    0.0052    0.0002
0.9500    0.0025    0.0823    0.0161    0.0002
```

The results for N = 1000 are:

```
Density   Sparse    Sparse    Full      Full
          multip.   retrieval multip.   retrieval 
0.0100    0.0088    7.5884    0.1216    0.1047
0.0200    0.0464    7.3136    0.1149    0.0521
0.0500    0.0827    7.0464    0.1733    0.0811
0.1000    0.1265    7.3251    0.0739    0.0563
0.2500    0.2088    7.5518    0.1392    0.0702
0.5000    0.5299    8.1214    0.0895    0.0579
0.7500    0.9524    9.0760    0.0836    0.1023
0.9500    1.3971    9.1553    0.1006    0.1208
```

The conclusion is simple. The sparse format is good if you have a lot of zeroes in a matrix. Besides you should NOT use a sparse matrix if you want to access cells one by one. Of course for smaller matrices differences are not so important.

Comment: But should the matrix-vector product in the first algorithm have roughly the same operations as *jac_iter* in the second? That product costs n^2 operations, plus n for adding c. *jac_iter* costs n-1 products and n-1 subtractions for each for loop plus a final division, making that 2n-1 operations for each component so 2n^2-n in total. OK one is n^2 per iteration and the other one twice as much, but that ought to double the time needed, not 10^4-ize it! Am I missing something?

Comment: In fact I am: the matrix-vector product costs n^2 products and n^2-n sums, thus getting to equality in operation number. So again I ask: am I missing something :)?

Comment: You have to remember that we don't know what matlab exactly does under the hood. I assume that if you allow matlab to do some operations on his own, then they will be performed faster because they are optimized. As to the execution time. Again we don't know what happens inside the matlabs engine and how much time each operation takes. Did you try to run your codes for different sizes of the problem (50x50, 100x100, 200x200, 500x500...)? I wonder how the execution time will be increasing for both algorithms.

Comment: I will try with some sizes. The times in the question are for a 2000x2000 matrix. Should I add the function that generated it?

Comment: I asked about different sizes because the results should confirm what is the complexity of both algorithms. You can generate results in anyway you want but the new function might be useful because it will automate everything.

Comment: Michał please see the edit. And how do I tag you? If I type at and MichałKomorowski, it just vanishes, as in @MichałKomorowski. And strangely, now it worked :). Some malfunction in the tagging function?

Comment: Possibly starting a post with a tag causes this malfunction? It happened already for math110 on math SX. Maybe I should ask on Meta. I will :).

Comment: No malfunction, it's intentional, since in a 2-person discussion there is no need for @-replies, which at comment start will automatically be removed, as stated [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238825/possible-malfunction-in-tagging-feature).

Comment: OK the problem is actually I meant 0.2 by 20 :). Anyway as for the `you shouldn't really use sparse matrices` part, I am forced to, since it's a University exercise :). Speaking of which, how do I optimize the algorithm for sparse matrices?

Comment: An idea is to use everything in sparse format, vectors included. That seems to reduce the needed time quite a lot.